# Best way to automatically remove comments from PHP code

Tags: php, comments, strip

What’s the best way to remove comments from a PHP file?

I want to do something similar to strip-whitespace() - but it shouldn't remove the line breaks as well.

For example,

I want this:

```
<?PHP
// something
if ($whatsit) {
    do_something(); # we do something here
    echo '<html>Some embedded HTML</html>';
}
/* another long
comment
*/
some_more_code();
?>
```

to become:

```
<?PHP
if ($whatsit) {
    do_something();
    echo '<html>Some embedded HTML</html>';
}
some_more_code();
?>
```

(Although if the empty lines remain where comments are removed, that wouldn't be OK.)

It may not be possible, because of the requirement to preserve embedded HTML - that’s what’s tripped up the things that have come up on Google.

Comment: Look into obfusacators. Although you'd have to find one that was configurable--to strip comments only.

Comment: Someone is bound to ask why: The code needs to go to a clients server to be deployed, so we want to make sure no  is there that shouldn't be.

Comment: Are you talking about inappropriate content in the comments?  Or is this just for size - smaller PHP scripts make almost no performance difference except in high usage or unusual cases (and Zend is usually a better answer than stripping them).

Comment: its where there are things in the comments that we don't want to risk being read. they shouldn't be there - but too late for that now.

Comment: I'd be reluctant to remove comments unless you're doing obfuscation. You may find a time when you need those comments on the client's server. Also, have you made it clear to them that the code is coming with comments? They may not like the surprise when they bring in different consultants...

Comment: @benlumley will you look into this question for a moment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040560/brandonaaron-jquery-mousewheel-fix-maximum-value

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I'd use [tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php). Here's my solution. It should work on both PHP 4 and 5:

```
$fileStr = file_get_contents('path/to/file');
$newStr  = '';

$commentTokens = array(T_COMMENT);
    
if (defined('T_DOC_COMMENT')) {
    $commentTokens[] = T_DOC_COMMENT; // PHP 5
}

if (defined('T_ML_COMMENT')) {
    $commentTokens[] = T_ML_COMMENT;  // PHP 4
}

$tokens = token_get_all($fileStr);

foreach ($tokens as $token) {    
    if (is_array($token)) {
        if (in_array($token[0], $commentTokens)) {
            continue;
        }
        
        $token = $token[1];
    }

    $newStr .= $token;
}

echo $newStr;
```

Comment: You should take out `$commentTokens` initialization out of the `foreach` block, otherwise +1 and thanks :)

Comment: @Raveren, you're damn right. I have no idea what was in my mind back then to put that piece of code inside the loop. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan I have been trying to implement this, but it's breaking a lot of code. Here's an example:
```
 ### Version ###

 const  MARKDOWNLIB_VERSION  =  "1.6.0";

 ### Simple Function Interface ###

 public static function defaultTransform($text) {
```
Becomes
```
 ### Version # const  MARKDOWNLIB_VERSION  =  "1.6.0";

 ### Simple Function Interface # public static function defaultTransform($text) {
```
Not sure if this will format well here...

Comment: @AndrewChristensen I can't reproduce it. What PHP version are you using?

Comment: How do we use this code snippent ? Create a file cleanup.php and put this code block  in ? Say we clean up a file called index.php, we get the output of $newStr and paste back into index.php ? Is that how this works ?

Answer (score 49):

Use `php -w <sourcefile>` to generate a file stripped of comments and whitespace, and then use a beautifier like [PHP_Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier) to reformat for readability.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - the other way was quicker to use, as all the bits were already on the server.

Comment: On a *nix box this would boil down to run on a console: `$ php -qw your_code.php | php_beautifier 2>/dev/null`. Beware that errors & Co. might still appear on screen -- to avoid that, just set `display_errors` to `Off` in your (CLI) `php.ini` file.

Comment: what is php -w and how to do this on windows 10?

Answer (score 10):

```
$fileStr = file_get_contents('file.php');
foreach (token_get_all($fileStr) as $token ) {
    if ($token[0] != T_COMMENT) {
        continue;
    }
    $fileStr = str_replace($token[1], '', $fileStr);
}

echo $fileStr;
```

Comment: I think the above snippet should work just fine. It's actually simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the function posted above, modified to recursively remove all comments from all PHP files within a directory and all its subdirectories:

```
function rmcomments($id) {
    if (file_exists($id)) {
        if (is_dir($id)) {
            $handle = opendir($id);
            while($file = readdir($handle)) {
                if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..")) {
                    rmcomments($id . "/" . $file); }}
            closedir($handle); }
        else if ((is_file($id)) && (end(explode('.', $id)) == "php")) {
            if (!is_writable($id)) { chmod($id, 0777); }
            if (is_writable($id)) {
                $fileStr = file_get_contents($id);
                $newStr  = '';
                $commentTokens = array(T_COMMENT);
                if (defined('T_DOC_COMMENT')) { $commentTokens[] = T_DOC_COMMENT; }
                if (defined('T_ML_COMMENT')) { $commentTokens[] = T_ML_COMMENT; }
                $tokens = token_get_all($fileStr);
                foreach ($tokens as $token) {
                    if (is_array($token)) {
                        if (in_array($token[0], $commentTokens)) { continue; }
                        $token = $token[1]; }
                    $newStr .= $token; }
                if (!file_put_contents($id, $newStr)) {
                    $open = fopen($id, "w");
                    fwrite($open, $newStr);
                    fclose($open);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

rmcomments("path/to/directory");
```

Answer (score 5):

A more powerful version: remove all comments in the folder

```
<?php
    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(__DIR__, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di);
    $fileArr = [];
    foreach($it as $file) {
        if(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "php") {
            ob_start();
            echo $file;
            $file = ob_get_clean();
            $fileArr[] = $file;
        }
    }
    $arr = [T_COMMENT, T_DOC_COMMENT];
    $count = count($fileArr);
    for($i=1; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $fileStr = file_get_contents($fileArr[$i]);
        foreach(token_get_all($fileStr) as $token) {
            if(in_array($token[0], $arr)) {
                $fileStr = str_replace($token[1], '', $fileStr);
            }
        }
        file_put_contents($fileArr[$i], $fileStr);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Following upon the accepted answer, I needed to preserve the line numbers of the file too, so here is a variation of the accepted answer:

```php
    /**
     * Removes the php comments from the given valid php string, and returns the result.
     *
     * Note: a valid php string must start with <?php.
     *
     * If the preserveWhiteSpace option is true, it will replace the comments with some whitespaces, so that
     * the line numbers are preserved.
     *
     *
     * @param string $str
     * @param bool $preserveWhiteSpace
     * @return string
     */
    function removePhpComments(string $str, bool $preserveWhiteSpace = true): string
    {
        $commentTokens = [
            \T_COMMENT,
            \T_DOC_COMMENT,
        ];
        $tokens = token_get_all($str);


        if (true === $preserveWhiteSpace) {
            $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
        }


        $s = '';
        foreach ($tokens as $token) {
            if (is_array($token)) {
                if (in_array($token[0], $commentTokens)) {
                    if (true === $preserveWhiteSpace) {
                        $comment = $token[1];
                        $lineNb = $token[2];
                        $firstLine = $lines[$lineNb - 1];
                        $p = explode(PHP_EOL, $comment);
                        $nbLineComments = count($p);
                        if ($nbLineComments < 1) {
                            $nbLineComments = 1;
                        }
                        $firstCommentLine = array_shift($p);

                        $isStandAlone = (trim($firstLine) === trim($firstCommentLine));

                        if (false === $isStandAlone) {
                            if (2 === $nbLineComments) {
                                $s .= PHP_EOL;
                            }

                            continue; // Just remove inline comments
                        }

                        // Stand-alone case
                        $s .= str_repeat(PHP_EOL, $nbLineComments - 1);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                $token = $token[1];
            }

            $s .= $token;
        }
        return $s;
    }
```

Note: this is for PHP 7+ (I didn't care about backward compatibility with older PHP versions).

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
* T_ML_COMMENT does not exist in PHP 5.
* The following three lines define it in order to
* preserve backwards compatibility.
*
* The next two lines define the PHP 5 only T_DOC_COMMENT,
* which we will mask as T_ML_COMMENT for PHP 4.
*/

if (! defined('T_ML_COMMENT')) {
    define('T_ML_COMMENT', T_COMMENT);
} else {
    define('T_DOC_COMMENT', T_ML_COMMENT);
}

/*
 * Remove all comment in $file
 */

function remove_comment($file) {
    $comment_token = array(T_COMMENT, T_ML_COMMENT, T_DOC_COMMENT);

    $input = file_get_contents($file);
    $tokens = token_get_all($input);
    $output = '';

    foreach ($tokens as $token) {
        if (is_string($token)) {
            $output .= $token;
        } else {
            list($id, $text) = $token;

            if (in_array($id, $comment_token)) {
                $output .= $text;
            }
        }
    }

    file_put_contents($file, $output);
}

/*
 * Glob recursive
 * @return ['dir/filename', ...]
 */

function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0) {
    $file_list = glob($pattern, $flags);

    $sub_dir = glob(dirname($pattern) . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    // If sub directory exist
    if (count($sub_dir) > 0) {
        $file_list = array_merge(
            glob_recursive(dirname($pattern) . '/*/' . basename($pattern), $flags),
            $file_list
        );
    }

    return $file_list;
}

// Remove all comment of '*.php', include sub directory
foreach (glob_recursive('*.php') as $file) {
    remove_comment($file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already use an editor like [UltraEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit), you can open one or multiple PHP file(s) and then use a **simple Find&Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)** with the following [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
(?s)/\*.*\*/
```

Beware the above regular expression also removes comments inside a string, i.e., in `echo "hello/*babe*/";` the `/*babe*/` would be removed too. Hence, it could be a solution if you have few files to remove comments from. In order to be absolutely sure it does not wrongly replace something that is not a comment, you would have to run the *Find&Replace* command and approve each time what is getting replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Bash solution: If you want to remove recursively comments from all PHP files starting from the current directory, you can write this one-liner in the terminal. (It uses `temp1` file to store PHP content for processing.)

**Note that this will strip all white spaces with comments.**

```
 find . -type f -name '*.php' | while read VAR; do php -wq $VAR > temp1  ;  cat temp1 > $VAR; done
```

Then you should remove `temp1` file after.

If [PHP_BEAUTIFER](https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier/) is installed **then you can get nicely formatted code without comments** with

```
 find . -type f -name '*.php' | while read VAR; do php -wq $VAR > temp1; php_beautifier temp1 > temp2;  cat temp2 > $VAR; done;
```

Then remove two files (`temp1` and `temp2`).

Answer (score 1):

For Ajax and JSON responses, I use the following PHP code, to remove comments from HTML/JavaScript code, so it would be smaller (about 15% gain for my code).

```
// Replace doubled spaces with single ones (ignored in HTML any way)
$html = preg_replace('@(\s){2,}@', '\1', $html);
// Remove single and multiline comments, tabs and newline chars
$html = preg_replace(
    '@(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|((?<!:)//.*)|[\t\r\n]@i',
    '',
    $html
);
```

It is short and effective, but it can produce unexpected results, if your code has bad syntax.

Comment: Doesn't this regexp remove comments in strings? I.e. in `echo "hello /*baby*/ boy";` wouldn't your regexp mistakenly remove `/*baby*/` in sting?

Comment: @MarcoDemaio It will. To avoid that, you will need parser, not some simple Regex, because you need to follow quotation states and know where comment resides and where you don't need them. JSON is not meant for complex data structures and you should avoid situations, where you have possibility that there will be some single or multi-line comments inside data.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `php --strip file.php` in a command prompt (for example., *cmd.exe*), and then browse to *[WriteCodeOnline](http://www.writephponline.com/phpbeautifier)*.

Here, *file.php* is your own file.

[image: 1]

Comment: Won't --strip (or -w) also strip the whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

In 2019 it could work like this:

```
<?php
/*   hi there !!!
here are the comments */
//another try

echo removecomments('index.php');

/*   hi there !!!
here are the comments */
//another try
function removecomments($f){
    $w=Array(';','{','}');
    $ts = token_get_all(php_strip_whitespace($f));
    $s='';
    foreach($ts as $t){
        if(is_array($t)){
            $s .=$t[1];
        }else{
            $s .=$t;
            if( in_array($t,$w) ) $s.=chr(13).chr(10);
        }
    }

    return $s;
}

?>
```

If you want to see the results, just let's run it first in [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP), and then you get a blank page, but if you right click and click on view source, you get your PHP script ... it's loading itself and it's removing all comments and also tabs.

I prefer this solution too, because I use it to speed up my framework one file engine "m.php" and after *php_strip_whitespace*, all source without this script I observe is slowest: I did 10 benchmarks, and then I calculate the math average (I think PHP 7 is restoring back the missing cr_lf's when it is parsing or it is taking a while when these are missing).

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that a less robust matching algorithm (simple regex, for instance) will start stripping here when it clearly shouldn't:

```
if (preg_match('#^/*' . $this->index . '#', $this->permalink_structure)) {
```

It might not affect your code, but eventually someone will get bit by your script.  So you will have to use a utility that understands more of the language than you might otherwise expect.

Answer (score 0):

`php -w` or `php_strip_whitespace($filename);`

[documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.php-strip-whitespace.php)

Comment: This is useful, but OP asked specifically for a solution that does not remove line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

for me this work correctly in LINUX and WINDOWS:

```
$php_0com = file_get_contents('file.php');
$php_0com = preg_replace('@/\*.*?\*/|\n\r@s', '', $php_0com);
$php_0com = trim(preg_replace('@(^<\?|//|#).*\r\n@', '', $php_0com));
print_r($php_0com);
```

note the difference in the TWO lines of code:

**@regex@s** vs **@regex@**

the modifier **`s`** allow search multi-line: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php