# A JSON parser for PHP that supports comments

Tags: php, json, comments

Can anyone suggest a JSON parser that allows any kind of comments, with PHP bindings - need the comments badly for config files but json_decode doesn't support them.

*(I am aware of: 1. other format such as YAML, 2. comments are not part of the standard)*

**Update:**

Why don't we use:

- YAML: Benchmarks show it's slower - and we might want to send the data over the wire - not sure if YAML is best for that.
- XML: too verbose - simple human editing is a requirement. And no need for the extended features of XML.
- INI: there is hierarchy and nesting of variable depth in the data. And we need a ubiquitous format as the data might be distributed with apps or work with apps in other languages.
- Pre-processing: data can be contributed and shared by users, tough to impose a requirement to pre-process before adding data to an app.

Comment: What are the comments for? Human or computer reading?

Comment: You could run the JSON string through a pre-processing parser which strips all comments

Comment: I can only second Gordon. Use a format which can give you what you expect from it, instead of raping another format which is just not for that purpose in its current state.

Comment: If they're for config files, then why not use parse_ini_file compatible .ini files?  or create your config files in PHP itself?  Both support comments and would be cheaper to parse than JSON using methods other than json_decode.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: It's not raping - it's consensual:) The standard does allow for parsers to support extensions.

Comment: @heldt: comments are for humans - for now - in any case, we would like the parser to ignore them gracefully.

Comment: [json5](https://github.com/json5/json5), end of

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### YAML

If you need portability and don't want any pre-processing or non-standard syntax, then YAML is probably the way to go. Though, beware of the [dangers and caveats of YAML](https://www.arp242.net/yaml-config.html#surprising-behaviour).

Most, if not all, of JSON is compatible with YAML (YAML is a superset of JSON), and it supports comments. So the initial switch is easy.

#### JSON with comments

I recently needed to migrate from [INI files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) in PHP to something that has support for integers and booleans, but still supported comments as well.

JSON seemed like a good format, except for supporting comments. If you want to make this work, you don't need a whole custom JSON parser. It can be made to work with simple wrapper that strips the comments uses the native `json_decode` after that. (This works for sane content that trusted people author. If you allow crazy inputs there is probably a way to break this.)

Code from [github.com/countervandalism/stillalive](https://github.com/countervandalism/stillalive/blob/v2018.11/src/Util.php#L21-L41), with the regex from [@makaveli_lcf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136663/319266):

```
class JsonUtil {
    /**
     * From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252511/319266
     * @return array|false
     */
    public static function load( $filename ) {
        $contents = @file_get_contents( $filename );
        if ( $contents === false ) {
            return false;
        }
        return json_decode( self::stripComments( $contents ), true );
    }
    /**
     * From https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252511/319266
     * @param string $str
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function stripComments( $str ) {
        return preg_replace( '![ \t]*//.*[ \t]*[\r\n]!', '', $str );
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the leading and trailing `!` in the regex for?

Comment: @JohnArcher Good question! The `!` bangs here serve as the regex delimiters – taking the place of the traditional `/` slashes. My regex here includes slashes itself, which means those would otherwise need to be escaped. You might also sometimes see `#`, `%` or `~` used as delimiters. See also [php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters](https://www.php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters).

Comment: That is interesting, thanks a lot. I tried this on regex101.com, but it does not work there. See this example: https://regex101.com/r/q6SFFT/1 If I fix the "unescaped delimiter" problem the site does not recognize `!` (or other delimiters) as delimiters but matches the character literally. Is this because the site simply does not support this, but PHP's `preg_replace()` does?

Comment: @JohnArcher The delimiters are not part of the pattern, they are only an encoding and do not change the behaviour of the regex. The website at your link has the delimiters already set (in light grey). This means a bang `!` within that, would be treated as literal part of the pattern, not as delimiter. Effectively, your link is running `/!…!/`, instead of `!…!` or `/…/`. Similarly, if I were to enter `/` there, it would also fail. As that would be `//…//` instead of `/…/`. See https://regex101.com/r/8Smo5h/1 and https://regex101.com/r/NVY6f1/1.

Comment: Note that the regular expression in this post doesn't handle strings that have comments embedded in them; `{ "hello": "world // blah" }` would replace to `{ "hello": "world`, which is invalid JSON.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following function to decode commented json:

```
function json_decode_commented($data, $assoc = false, $maxDepth = 512, $opts = 0) {
  $data = preg_replace('~
    (" (?:\\\\. | [^"])*+ ") | \# [^\v]*+ | // [^\v]*+ | /\* .*? \*/
  ~xs', '$1', $data);

  return json_decode($data, $assoc, $maxDepth, $opts);
}
```

It supports all PHP-style comments: /*, #, //. String values are preserved as is.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted one. btw, I've created a package and use this solution than my own: unional/jsonc

Comment: Actually, I notice `| \# [^\v]*+` is not necessary and breaks certain cases. Is there a reason to have that?

Comment: @unional, the only reason is to support # ..... comment till line end ....
It should not break anything, because strings are already excluded from processing.

Comment: I have a test case that doesn’t work. You can try it on the just-func.jsonc in GitHub justland/just-func under the json-schema folder.

Comment: @unional, thank you for bug reporting. Changed the code to improve escape character handling: \<any char> will be skipped in string literals now.

Comment: You are welcome. Is it common to use `#` for comment in jsonc? I use VSCode and also as in json (JavaScript), only `//` and `/* */` are acceptable comment formats.

Btw, I have created a jsonc package and used your implementation instead of the one I have. Will add your name on it for attribution. :)
https://github.com/unional/jsonc-php

Comment: It's a bash/python style comments. You may remove "| \# [^\v]*+" part to exclude their support. Anyway, it may be better to support all-style comments in generic function.
Thanks.

Comment: I found myself needing to modify VSCode workspace files programmatically, it would be wonderful if there was a way to retain the comments

Comment: I think `$data` should be renamed as `$json`, correct?

Comment: You can give it any name. It's a data string in json format, right.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned [json5](https://json5.org/)

```js
{
  // comments
  unquoted: 'and you can quote me on that',
  singleQuotes: 'I can use "double quotes" here',
  lineBreaks: "Look, Mom! \
No \\n's!",
  hexadecimal: 0xdecaf,
  leadingDecimalPoint: .8675309, andTrailing: 8675309.,
  positiveSign: +1,
  trailingComma: 'in objects', andIn: ['arrays',],
  "backwardsCompatible": "with JSON",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to allow your users to insert comments as unused fields in the JSON structure:

```
{
  "color": "red",
  "color//": "may be red, green or blue"
}
```

If you only use your JSON for input, and it's never machine-saved, you could abuse the format to use the same field repeatedly, incidentally achieving a near-wipe of the comments when parsing (as usually only the first or the last value of a field will be retained in a parsed structure):

```
{
  "color": "red",      "//":"may be red, green or blue",
  "shape": "circle",   "//":"use circle, square or triangle",
  "timeout": 5,        "//":"timeout in seconds; default is 10"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Comments are not part of JSON, so a "JSON parser" is not required to accept comments..

I'd use YAML. Even if parsing is slightly slower (PHP has a native JSON parser but no native YAML parser) it's probably neglectible and if it's not, you can always cache the parsed object. Besides that, since the PHP JSON parser does not support comments you'd have to use a non-native one, i.e. it most likely wouldn't be faster than the YAML parser (assuming both are well-written)

Comment: A JSON encoder MUST NOT output comments. A JSON decoder MAY accept and ignore comments. http://blog.getify.com/2010/06/json-comments/ . If the feature is useful there's no harm in siding with the designer of the spec.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need inline or multi-line comments and only use `//` style comments on lines by themselves - here's a reliable way to strip them without using regex:

**settings.json:**

```json
// global settings for my app
{
    "MAIN_DIR" : "/path/to/dir/",
    "DB_NAME"  : "my_app",

    // auth keys for example.com
    "ID"     : "123ABC",
    "SECRET" : "1834966f74fbc8b672296a9356eec43f"
}
```

**read_settings.php**

```php
$lines = file('settings.json');
$lines = array_map('trim', $lines);
$lines = array_filter($lines, fn($v) => strpos($v, '//') !== 0); 
$settings = json_decode(implode(PHP_EOL, $lines), true);
```