# Removing comments from a group of php files via command line in Windows

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of files and I would like to send them to deployment sans any comments but with whitespace intact (so that I can make any quick changes in production in emergency cases).

The comments can be either single line comments (`#`, `//`) or multi line syntax `/**/` and at any indentation level.

I want to create a batch file that when executed from any directory reads all php files and strips their comments.

I am not even sure what to try. I know I can fetch all the files with .php extension easily and loop through them. Replacing their content is easy enough as well. What I am stuck on is how to remove the comments.

Comment: It may be possible to do this with batch file but it is better to choose another way (programming language). Batch files are not for such tasks - usually they call external tool for the real work.

Comment: So what would you suggest I do? Like what programming language would have such a function.

Comment: Python and Perl are freely available and support regexes. If you want a specific tool, then there are a number of Windows ports of UNIX tools such as `awk` and `sed`. For a full tool set you might get `Cygwin`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643113/regex-to-strip-comments-and-multi-line-comments-and-empty-lines

Comment: @Squashman Those answers don't deal with cases where `//` or `#` comes inside a pair of quotes. The tokenizer looks interesting, I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @Liturgist Regex can do it but it will not work for some cases. I was more hoping there would be a function that some language had.

Comment: @Achshar well I am sure you know that SO is not a code writing service.  I at least searched the website to find something close for you.  You could at least attempt to write something in some language.  I can tell you that writing a batch file would not even be in my top 5 solutions for this.  Batch files cannot do Regular Expression string replacement.  You should re-tag your question with something other than batch-file and cmd.

Comment: @Squashman done. And yeah I spent an hour googling this, and read all the other answers on SO. None of them fit by requirement and I am not knowledgeable enough to write my own regex yet, which is what brings me to SO.

Comment: I know it is old, but will this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code

Comment: Yeah tokenizer seems to be the only option right now. If nothing else comes up that's what I'll go with.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to do it, but I think the most efficient will be to use regular expressions.
I'm not a RegExp guru, but I know that you can use grep (or any powerfull text editor such as Notepad++, sublimetext, et...) to replace expressions highlighted to empty string.

For example, in Sublime Text, I've tested this regular expression, which find any multiple lines comment :

```
\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/|//.*|#.*
```

Quick Explanation :

- the regexp is made of 3, with an OR symbol inside ( the pipe symbol `|`)
- the first expression mean "something starting with /*, any character, or any blank character , and finishing with */"
- the second means "any expression starting with `//` and any character following
- the third means "any expression starting with `#` and any character following

Once you've set this search expression in sublime text, you can replace what it did return with a "blank" replacement.

Comment: Will this deal with comments that are in the middle of the line? or if `//` or `#` appears inside a double or single quote? That would mess with it.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the comments that are inside quotes will be removed ! For the comments in middle of line (/* */ style), they should be removed OK !