# General utility to remove/strip all comments from source code in various languages?

Tags: php, python, c

I am looking for a command-line tool that removes all comments from an input
file and returns the stripped output. It'd be nice it supports popular
programming languages like c, c++, python, php, javascript, html, css, etc.  It
has to be syntax-aware as opposed to regexp-based, since the latter will catch
the pattern in source code strings as well. Is there any such tool?

I am fully aware that comments are useful information and often leaving them
as they are is a good idea. It's just that my focus is on different use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such tool exists yet.

Answer (score 5):

[`cloc`](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/#strip_comments), a free Perl script, can do this.

> #### Remove Comments from Source Code
>
> How can you tell if cloc correctly identifies comments? One way to convince yourself cloc is doing the right thing is to use its `--strip-comments` option to remove comments and blank lines from files, then compare the stripped-down files to originals.

It supports [**a lot** of languages](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/#Languages).

Comment: I'm sorry, the tool misses a lot of comments -- even the most rudimentary comment instances -- on a test python file. Isn't it regexp-based? I do not know if you ever tried it, but it seems unusable for this purpose.

Comment: @otz: It's a mature tool that hasn't failed me on any of my uses, including Python scripts.  I do not think that you are using it correctly.  For example, the command `perl /path/to/cloc-1.51.pl --strip-comments=n .` executed in a directory with a file `foo.py` will create a `foo.py.n` file with comments and blank lines removed.  I would like to see an example of what you claim isn't working (and I'm sure cloc's developer would, too).

Comment: failed on javascript inline comments: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nBVN3S2w8G/

Answer (score 3):

What you want can be done with emacs scripting.

I wrote this script for you which does exactly what you want and can be easily extended to any language.

**Filename: kill-comments**

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                         

import subprocess                                                         
import sys                                                                
import os                                                                 

target_file = sys.argv[1]                                                 

command =   "emacs -batch -l ~/.emacs-batch " + \                         
    target_file + \                                                       
    " --eval '(kill-comment (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))'" + \  
    " -f save-buffer"                                                     

#to load a custom .emacs script (for more syntax support),                
#use -l <file> in the above command                                       

#print command                                                            

fnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')                                             
subprocess.call(command, shell = True, stdout = fnull, stderr = fnull)    
fnull.close()
```

to use it just call:

```
kill-comments <file-name>
```

To add any language to it edit ~/.emacs-batch and add that language's major mode.
You can find syntax aware modes for basically everything you could want at http://www.emacswiki.org.

As an example, here is my ~/.emacs-batch file.  It extends the above script to remove comments from javascript files. (I have [javascript.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JavaScriptMode) in my ~/.el directory)

```
(setq load-path (append (list (concat (getenv "HOME") "/.el")) load-path))    
(load "javascript")                                               
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.js$" . javascript-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

With the javascript addition this will remove comments from all the filetypes you mentioned as well as many more.

Good Luck and happy coding!

Comment: lol. though it isn't robust enough as emacs highlighting on most languages is regexp-based (and therefore would catch certain weirdly formulated comments in strings, i am impressed by your idea :) What I want though, is a syntax-aware tool. Therefore, it'd have to have language parsers built in (JavaCC .jj .jjt files anyone?)

Comment: You should try it on some test files before dismissing it.  Emacs syntax highlighting is quite good.

Comment: tried the (kill-comment ARG) on emacs. am satisfied by its accuracy in general. it's certainly a million times more accurate than that cloc tool suggested on this page. so thanks for that. but again, kill-comment function depends on the syntax highlighting in emacs, most of which are regexp-based. so it really depends on how good the <language>-mode.el is. but again, i like your idea.

Comment: "Ideally" you would want an embedded compiler/interpreter for the language, but consider that actually determining what is a comment and what isn't could possibly be uncomputable given certain pathological languages (thus take forever), in which case you'd actually want to go for the regex-based approach to remove "standard" comments! For many languages a pull parse is not required to remove comments and the regex approach can be proven correct (this is what the pre-processor might do anyway). Remember to vote up answers you find useful / pick one as "the" answer as per the etiquette here.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Dixon's [response to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code) on stripping comments from a script might be worth looking at.

Comment: OP mentions multiple languages but Paul Dixons approach mentioned just works for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such a tool - which isn't the same as saying there isn't one.

I once started to design one, but it quickly gets insane - not helped by the comment rules in C and C++.

```
/\
*  Comment? *\
/
```

(Answer: yes!)

```
"/\
* Comment? *\
/"
```

(Answer: no!)

To do the job reasonably, you have to be aware of:

- Language comment conventions
- Language quoted string conventions (Python and Perl are enough to drive you insane here)
- Escape conventions (Shell gets you here - along with the quotes)

These combine to make the job tolerably close to impossible.

I ended up with a program, *scc*, to strip C and C++ comments.  Its torture test includes worse examples than the comments shown above - and it does a decent job.  But extending that to do shell or Perl or Python or (take your pick) was sufficiently non-trivial that I did not do it.

Comment: yup. i know. i could program such a tool myself with javacc and available syntax .jj files (there are tons of them available, for all popular languages). i was just wondering if anyone ever tried it yet. (all of my questions are never fully satisfactorily answered btw..)

Answer (score -1):

You might coax [GNU Source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) into doing this.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but it isn't fully syntax-aware, it seems to me. it is semi-syntax-aware as it is essentially regexp-based, but regexps are "structured" depending on languages.