# Python 3 regular expression to find multiline comment

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, comments

I'm trying to find comment blocks in PHP source code using regular expressions in Python 3. The PHP comments are in this format:

```
/**
 * This is a very short block comment
 */
```

Now I came up with the following regular expression:

```
'/\*\*[.]+?\*/'
```

I figure that -in combination with the DOTALL flag- should do it, but no. It doesn't find anything. Strange thing is that when I remove the trailing slash, like this:

```
'/\*\*[.]+?\*'
```

then it finds the following string:

```
/**\n\t*
```

I have no idea why the regex can't find an asterisk followed by a slash... I checked the file that I'm searching to double check I didn't have a typo in the comment (I didn't).
Also a slash is no special character in regex, so I wouldn't have to escape it. (I tried, but it didn't help.)

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my regex? :)

By the way, I also came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898636/java-regular-expression-for-php-comment)! thread where someone tried to do the same in Java. The final winning answer finished his regular expression the same way I do now, so I'm clueless :( Could this be a bug in Python regex or am I completely missing something?

Any help is much appreciated! :D

Comment: Why do you have `[.]` in your pattern ? As opposed to just .+

Comment: Well, because at first I used [.\s] without the DOTALL flag. After I removed the \s and added the DOTALL flag, the square brackets just kept lingering there. However, no that I removed them they seemed to cause the problem. If anyone cares to explain that? As far as my regex knowledge goes '.+' should match the same things as [.]+ right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `re.DOTALL` flag to make the `.` character match newlines:

```
re.compile(r'/\*\*.+?\*/', re.DOTALL)
```

(As a side note, PHP block comments can start with `/*`, not just `/**`.)

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include the DOTALL flag in my post. I did it in my program though, and it doesn't work. The problem seem to be that the last / is not recognized for some reason :(

Comment: Just now I noticed you don't use []'s around the . in your expression. When I remove the []'s in my program the regex works! Could you (or someone else) explain why it works without brackets but doesn't work with them? Thanks for your answer anyway! It works now! :)

Comment: Ah, perhaps that was your problem, `[.]` will match a literal period whereas `.` will match any character.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering why they didn't match the same thing, but now that I thin about it, why would you ever want a . in between []'s... it makes no sense! Thanks for your time and help! :)

Comment: This will not work correctly in PHP because you can have comment characters inside of quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
r'\/\*\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*\/'
```

(this is the regex used by some CSS parsers for `/* CSS comments */`, so I believe it is pretty solid)

It won't match the exact format including line breaks and the inner asterisks, but you can work around it. This will match:

```
/**
 * This is a very short block comment
 */
```

But also:

```
/** This is a very short block comment */
```

And even:

```
/** This is a very short block comment 
*/
```

To match the exact format of docblocks, you'd need a real parser, not regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your expression works, though like you said, it needs some tweaking to work according to my needs :) Going with jtbandes' solution, though, because his does exactly what I want at the moment :) Thanks!

Comment: Both do the same thing. His is simpler; I just copy & pasted from something I had.

Comment: This could not work in PHP because it does not account for comment characters which may appear in quoted text. Therefore, it will extract things which are not comments.