# Regex expression for multiline comment in Python

Tags: python, regex, comments, multiline

I want to write a regex expression for multiline comment in Python. I was trying to modify this expression for multiline comment in Java, but I wasn't able to do it, because in Python multiline comment works in a different way.

Regex expression for Java:

```
(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
```

An example of multiline comment in Python:

```
''' comment comment
comment comment
'''
```

or

```
""" comment comment
comment comment
"""
```

Comment: You seem to confuse multiline string literals with multiline comments. See a [regex for multiline Python comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081882/python-3-regular-expression-to-find-multiline-comment).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it seems that this link is offering a solution for a regular expression in Python for PHP multiline comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Technically, multiline strings != multiline comments. But that's aside from the point)

The regex `(['"])\1\1(.*?)\1{3}` should work, but make sure you use `re.DOTALL`.

- `(['"])` Find a `'` or `"` and capture it in `\1`
- `\1\1` Find 2 more of the same quotes
- `(.*?)` Capture everything until...
- `\1{3}` Find three more identical quotes

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does this expression allows break lines? Because I was testing it in this website: [link](https://regex101.com/r/wY1hU9/1#python) and it only recognized if the quotation marks were in the same line.

Comment: Did you see this: **but make sure you use re.DOTALL**? I put it there for a reason. Used like this: `re.compile("regex", re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 0):

the below work fine to catch the multi line comment block in python

```
\"""(.|[\r\n])*\"""
```