# How to match non-enquoted things?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I have the following RegEx to remove commentary from a PHP file:
`%/\*.*?\*/%s`

The side effect is, that on use of `glob` like `glob($basedir . '/*')` it starts removing everything midcode...

So how do I tell the regex to not match when there are quotes in front of it or behind it?

Comment: Use `preg_match` to find if there's any occupancy of "there are quotes in front of it or behind it" and cast it in boolean and use in `if-else statements`. First idea what came in my mind after reading this

Comment: This is nontrivial because you could certainly also have quotes inside comments, and then things get hairy pretty rapidly. This means that any regex-based solution will be suboptimal - in essence you need a complete PHP language parser and use that to identify comments correctly.

Comment: This can't be done except in the simplest cases. Most probably, **only PHP** can parse PHP (due to regexes and other non-trivial constructs). For Perl, this has [been proven some time ago](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663393).

Comment: Seems to match **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
%[^'"]{1}/\*.*?\*/[^'"]{1}%s
```

It include not simple or double quote before /* and after */