# jquery-mousewheel fix maximum value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, mousewheel

I am using brandonaaron jquery-mousewheel plugin in

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

with a zoom function on [Pan Zoom](http://benlumley.co.uk/dev/panzoom/example/index.html).

The problem is i cant fix a maximum value to infinely scroll down and scroll up.
How can i fix this problem.

I have tried it simple function but i cant able to make mouse wheel here

```
var zoomLevel = 100;
var maxZoomLevel = 105;
var minZoomLevel = 95;

function zoom(zm) {
 var img=document.getElementById("pic");
 if(zm > 1){
    if(zoomLevel < maxZoomLevel){
        zoomLevel++;
    }else{
        return;
    }
 }else if(zm < 1){
    if(zoomLevel > minZoomLevel){
        zoomLevel--;
    }else{
        return;
    }
 }
 wid = img.width;
 ht = img.height;
 img.style.width = (wid*zm)+"px";
 img.style.height = (ht*zm)+"px";
 img.style.marginLeft = -(img.width/2) + "px";
 img.style.marginTop = -(img.height/2) + "px";
}​
```

How to give maximum value and minimum value in mousewheel function

Comment: not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to make it so that you can't zoom in or out beyond a certain level?

Comment: @benlumley yes thats what i am trying to implement here

Answer (score 0):

the plugin doesn't have a concept of a zoomlevel - so this approach won't work. Instead, it continually zooms in/out and tracks state by the current size of the image - which it increases/decreases as you zoom.

You can limit how far 'out' you can zoom with the min_width and min_height options - currently max is not implemented, but the same logic could be used to add max_width and max_height too.