# removing php comments with replace tool using regex in phpstorm

Tags: php, regex, comments, phpstorm

How do I remove multiline comments from php files with regex? I tried "/\*(.*\n)*\*/" but it fails. All it does is starts with "/*" and stops at the last occurrence of "*/".

Comment: [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). `/\*(.+?)\*/s`

Comment: Regex might not be able to deal with all edge cases. Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/503871/1578604).

Comment: /\\*(.+?)\\*/ works if comment is on single line

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the tenub comment.

The final solution for all php comments looks like this:

`/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|(?<!http:)//.*`

Where

1) `/\*[\s\S]*?\*/` for `/*comments*/`

2) `(?<!http:)//.*` for single line `//comment` escaping urls starting with `http://` 
(it would be better to prevent the ones preceded by `"` or `'` from showing but I'm good for now)

Oh and tenub if you post a corrected answer instead of the comment. I'll accept it. Cos you helped ty)

Comment: A more generic regex would be `/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|//.*` because `[\s\S]` will be able to match every character.

Comment: Thank you Jerry. Well I really should learn regex sometime. It's unbelievably useful.

Comment: +1 for `[\s\S]`, which seems to be the only solution in PhpStorm to match all `.` inclusively new line characters (searched pretty long to find that).