# sed: How to delete everything in a string after two slashes //?

Tags: sed

I have a line with the code

```
require_once(PATH_ROOT).'/calls/inumber.php'); //this is a comment<br>
```

I want to delete everything with SED after the //. My first try was

```
sed -i 's/[//].*//' file;
```

But that deletes everthing after (PATH.ROOT).'/
I want to remove the comment, not the PATH. Ir is not in the sample above, but how can I exclude SED, not to delete after http:// cause there are two // too.

**EDIT:** Ok, the quest is, to remove all One-Line-Comments that starts with at least two slashes. It doesnt matter what letters/numbers/signs follow, replace it with nothing. The only exception is http(s):// that should be skipped. Examples and results:
$a=5; //first comment
    $a=5;

$b=10; ////// second comment
    $b=10;

$c=15; /// /*&/$%§$%&/& third comment
$c=15;

/////////////////////////////
should be empty string

/*test comment*/
/*test comment*/ --> no change cause there are no TWO slashes

Summary: everything after // should be removed (incl the two //) except the http(s)://

Comment: @Xen2050 You're correct, no answers in comments.

Comment: What language is this, where URL's (with //) and "comments" of `//////////////////` and `/// /*&/$%§$%&/&` are valid?

Comment: In PHP comments start with //. It doesnt matter what follows after that //<br>https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_syntax_comments or for url:<br> https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_filter7

Comment: What if the slashes are inside quotes?

Comment: @noobee You know that PHP comments like that are ended with `?>` and comments can also start with `#` or `/*`, they're too complicated to all be recognized with a small sed search IMO (especially considering you can have quoted `//`'s in valid PHP). Do you really just want to remove all PHP comments?

Comment: Yes I want to delete all PHP comments. First try is to remove one-line-comments. That seems not so difficult I thought. When removing the // and alle the content behind I just have to look, that there is no ":" before cause this could be an url like http://, ftp:// ...
A one-line-comment with "#" ends at the end of the line I think. And a one-line-comment with"/*" ends with "*/".
Multiline comments are not important till now. I think it would be more difficult to remove such comments

Answer (score 1):

You can use greedy nature of quantifiers to always delete only the last occurrence

```
$ cat ip.txt
require_once(PATH_ROOT).'/calls/inumber.php'); //this is a comment<br>
http://foo/123 //commenting stuff
a//b/c/d 1//23/4/5 //commented

$ sed 's|\(.*\)//.*|\1|' ip.txt
require_once(PATH_ROOT).'/calls/inumber.php'); 
http://foo/123 
a//b/c/d 1//23/4/5
```

- `sed` allows [different delimiters to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/use-slashes-in-sed-replace), this helps to avoid having to escape `//`

  - `[//]` is same as `[/]`, meaning it matches a single `/`
- `\(.*\)//.*` use capture group for portion of the line before last set of `//` so that you can put it back in replacement section using `\1`

Comment: Ok, that removes comments like "//this is a comment" -> but not comments like "///////I am a long comment" or comments like "// // // // I am a long comment"<br> Can you do it with SED ?

Comment: I'd suggest that you edit the question to add all possible cases along with complete expected output for that..  the question as it stands doesn't explain these scenarios..

Comment: Thx for hint. I edited my question. I hope I explained it a bit better -.-

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've changed the question (a lot) here's a sed that shouldn't remove any URLs (file:// or http:// or https:// or anything:// ) - it ignores `://` but otherwise deletes everything after two slashes:

```
sed 's|\([^:]\)//.*$|\1|'
```

It matches anything not a `:` (saving that character) followed by `//` and anything to the end of the line, only putting back the first non-`:` character.

---

```
sed 's|//[^/]*$||'
```

`s`earch for `//` then anything not a slash `[^/]` zero or more times `*` then the end of the line `$`, and replace it with nothing.

If you wanted to match & delete any whitespace before a comment too, you could use the whitespace character class `\s`

```
sed 's|\s*//[^/]*$||'
```

Note that you can't have a slash inside a comment, since that would match URL's as comments, unless you recognized and excluded URL's.

---

Just in case you want to keep the `//`'s (since you say "*delete everything... after the //"*) you could just put them back:

```
sed 's|//[^/]*$|//|'
```

---

Note: To just remove all PHP comments, follow this answer [Best way to automatically remove comments from PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code)

Comment: I edited my question above. Can you show my the sed-command for deleting everthing after // incl. the // ? THX