# A regex to remove JS comment on PHP but ignore text inside String

Tags: javascript, php, regex

We've tried many solutions about how to remove JS comment by regular expression, but there's one case which always breaks my JS:

```
const a = "/*";
const b = "*/";
```

We commonly use `Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"` on our script so it always break our JS.

I'm looking for a regex that can ignore the searching within

> "", '', ``

string in JS or any other solution.

Thanks.

Comment: FOr what it is worth: In my experience: using regex for these kind of things always bites you in your ass, sooner or later.

Comment: This is something that would be better solved by using something like `uglify` on the JavaScript at application build time.

Comment: @anubhava currently I'm using      '|\/\*.*\*\/|sU'     to search multi line comment.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava but it just supports PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead after your final `/` to make sure it's not followed by a `*` like so:

```
\/\*.*\/(?!\*)
```

Example https://regexr.com/4m025